# Decimal in Mysql

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a table with many columns. Between them there are AB and AL both decimal(14,3) .
Now I have to create a new table like this:

```
create table new as
select AB, AL, (AB/AL)*100 AS M from my_table;
```

Mysql give me some warnings like: "1265 Data truncated for column M at row 2".

Is it warning me that the new number will be rounded? Is it safe?

Now the new column M is a decimal(24,7) but I need only a rounded DECIMAL(14, 3).
Do I have to do an alter table or there is a way to do that in the create statement?

I have a huge database with many columns like these so I need to keep the table size minim

Comment: "I have a table with many columns." This is sometimes indicative of poor (i.e. non-normalized) design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the maths
 an example 1.0 / 0.3  are both ok for a decimal(14,3) but their result when applied with your formula produces 333.333333....

there likely will be rounding errors but only minor ones if you only need 14,3 just use 14,3 as convering a 24,7 to a 14,3 will be the same as just making a 14,3.

Your data will be truncated, but not likely enough for it to effect you, Trial it first to be safe

Comment: If I have AB, AL as BIGINT mysql generate a decimal(26,4) and warning me the truncation. How can I decide if i want a decimal(20,6) or decimal(14,3) in the creation statement

Comment: are you going to eventually end with a 14,3 ? if so use that. Its your choice. I have no idea what your data is for or how accurate it needs to be. Both ways will have some loss20,6 is less loss vs more storage

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain good my question. Mysql If I have AB, AL as BIGINT mysql generates a decimal(26,4). Suppose that I would like to have a decimal(20,6) and I do an alter table: I will have all zeros after 4 digits, because Mysql just truncated the number. How can I write in the create statement that (AB/AL)*100 have to be a decimal(20,6)?

Comment: with `CAST((AB/AL)*100 AS DECIMAL(20,6))`